# call iframe function from parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call a javascript function in ifram from parent window. 
i have a jsp page which contains an iframe. 
jsp page is served by "a.yenama.net" server and iframe is served "b.yenama.net" server.

```
<iframe width="1200" height="640" name="data" id="dataId" >
</iframe>   
<br/>
<input type="button" name="data" value="Save data" onclick="callSaveData();" />
```

tried below code from parent jsp page and recieved permission denied error in IE

```
window.frames['data'].callData();
```

also tried

```
document.getElementById('dataId').contentWindow.callData(); //didn't work
```

### Function in iframe

```
window.callData = function(){
   alert('Iframe function');
}
```

your help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by declaring your function in a common .js file
Therefore, you can access your function from wherever you want.

Have a nice day

Comment: common function isn't possible, as the iframe is content is served by a different team(like a third party)

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you to use jquery.load method instead of iframe to load your second page in a div of first page and then you can call any methods from both the pages

```
$('#result').load('PageWhichYouAreOpeningInIFrame.html');
```

or if you still wants to go with IFrame then you can use:

[Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)

http://api.jquery.com/load/